# Merely setting webViewClient causes links to be opened inside webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Normally, when a link is clicked inside a WebView, an intent causes the web browser or another activity supporting that intent to open.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

However, when I merely set an empty WebViewClient…

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {});
setContentView(webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

…links are opened within the WebView and no intents are fired! How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

> To open links clicked by the user, simply provide a `WebViewClient` for your `WebView`, using `setWebViewClient()`. For example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

> That's it. Now all links the user clicks load in your WebView.

And

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

> If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. **If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url**

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` defaults to returning `false`

Comment: So is there a way to achieve both? by a return parameter value, or call the proper method which fires the intent? or must I implement this sort of thing myself?

Comment: If you want to handle it within your app and also let the system handle it simply launch an ACTION_VIEW intent with the url of the page.